# EmojiconEditText Not work <requestFocus />

Tags: android, android-edittext, emoji

I'm trying to do the en underlined in my EditText, but I can not do it extends emojis why.

I have tried many things, but do not work.

Xml

```
com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
.
<requestFocus />
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this.such as

```
<com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
    android:id="@+id/editEmojicon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ie32d emojicon"
    emojicon:emojiconSize="28sp" >

    <requestFocus />

    <com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText />
```

Comment: </com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText>  and firstly not work, I need delete all edittext and put again, then it works